# No visible @interface for ***** declares *****

Tags: swift, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to Objective-c. I am using swiftui to make my app.
But need to implant objective-c code for BLE. all work until I get this code

in .h file

```
- (void) setPackageBroadcast: (BOOL) broadcast;
```

and in .m file

```
- (void)setPackageBroadcast:(BOOL)broadcast {
[self._parameter setBroadcast:broadcast];
}
```

and I am getting the Error in .m file
"No visible @interface for 'ESPTaskParameter' declares the selector 'setBroadcast:'"

following is the all the code in two file

ESPTouchTask.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ESPTouchResult.h"
#import "ESPTouchDelegate.h"
#import "ESPAES.h"

#define ESPTOUCH_VERSION    @"SDK-v1.1.0"

#define DEBUG_ON   YES

@interface ESPTouchTask : NSObject

@property (atomic,assign) BOOL isCancelled;

- (id)initWithApSsid:(NSString *)apSsid andApBssid:(NSString *)apBssid andApPwd:(NSString *)apPwd andAES:(ESPAES *)aes;

/**
* Constructor of EsptouchTask
*
* @param apSsid
*            the Ap's ssid
* @param apBssid
*            the Ap's bssid
* @param apPassword
*            the Ap's password
* @param isSsidHidden
*            whether the Ap's ssid is hidden
*/
- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd;

/**
* Deprecated
*/
- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd andIsSsidHiden: (BOOL) isSsidHidden __deprecated_msg("Use initWithApSsid:(NSString *) andApBssid:(NSString *) andApPwd:(NSString *) instead.");

/**
* Constructor of EsptouchTask
*
* @param apSsid
*            the Ap's ssid
* @param apBssid
*            the Ap's bssid
* @param apPassword
*            the Ap's password
* @param isSsidHidden
*            whether the Ap's ssid is hidden
* @param timeoutMillisecond(it should be >= 15000+6000)
*               millisecond of total timeout
* @param context
*            the Context of the Application
*/
- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd andTimeoutMillisecond: (int) timeoutMillisecond;

/**
* Constructor of EsptouchTask
*
* @param apSsid
*            the Ap's ssid
* @param apBssid
*            the Ap's bssid
* @param apPassword
*            the Ap's password
* @param isSsidHidden
*            whether the Ap's ssid is hidden
* @param timeoutMillisecond(it should be >= 15000+6000)
*               millisecond of total timeout
* @param context
*            the Context of the Application
*/
- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd andIsSsidHiden: (BOOL) isSsidHidden andTimeoutMillisecond: (int) timeoutMillisecond  __deprecated_msg("Use initWithApSsid:(NSString *) andApBssid:(NSString *) andApPwd:(NSString *) andTimeoutMillisecond:(int) instead.");
  ......
* Set boradcast or multicast when post config info
* @param broadcast YES is boradcast, NO is multicast
*/
- (void) setPackageBroadcast: (BOOL) broadcast;

@end
```

ESPTouchTask.m

```
#import "ESPTouchTask.h"

#import "ESP_NetUtil.h"
#import "ESPTouchTaskParameter.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  .....
#define ONE_DATA_LEN    3

@interface ESPTouchTask ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData *_apSsid;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData *_apBssid;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData *_apPwd;

@property (nonatomic,strong) ESPTaskParameter *_parameter;

@property (atomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *_bssidTaskSucCountDict;

@property (atomic,strong) NSCondition *_esptouchResultArrayCondition;

@property (nonatomic,assign) __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier _backgroundTask;

@property (nonatomic,strong) id<ESPTouchDelegate> _esptouchDelegate;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData *_localInetAddrData;

@end

@implementation ESPTouchTask

- (id)initWithApSsid:(NSString *)apSsid andApBssid:(NSString *)apBssid andApPwd:(NSString *)apPwd andAES:(ESPAES *)aes
{
NSLog(@"Welcome Esptouch %@",ESPTOUCH_VERSION);
if (apSsid==nil||[apSsid isEqualToString:@""])
{
    perror("ESPTouchTask initWithApSsid() apSsid shouldn't be null or empty");
}
// the apSsid should be null or empty
//    assert(apSsid!=nil&&![apSsid isEqualToString:@""]);
if (apPwd == nil)
{
    apPwd = @"";
}

self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask init");
    }
    if (aes == nil) {
        self._apSsid = [ESP_ByteUtil getBytesByNSString:apSsid];
        self._apPwd = [ESP_ByteUtil getBytesByNSString:apPwd];
    } else {
        self._apSsid = [aes AES128EncryptData:[ESP_ByteUtil getBytesByNSString:apSsid]];
        self._apPwd = [aes AES128EncryptData:[ESP_ByteUtil getBytesByNSString:apPwd]];
    }
    self._apBssid = [ESP_NetUtil parseBssid2bytes:apBssid];
    self._parameter = [[ESPTaskParameter alloc]init];
    
    // check whether IPv4 and IPv6 is supported
    NSString *localInetAddr4 = [ESP_NetUtil getLocalIPv4];
    if (![ESP_NetUtil isIPv4PrivateAddr:localInetAddr4]) {
        localInetAddr4 = nil;
    }
    NSString *localInetAddr6 = [ESP_NetUtil getLocalIPv6];
    [self._parameter setIsIPv4Supported:localInetAddr4!=nil];
    [self._parameter setIsIPv6Supported:localInetAddr6!=nil];
    
    // create udp client and udp server
    self._client = [[ESPUDPSocketClient alloc]init];
    self._server = [[ESPUDPSocketServer alloc]initWithPort: [self._parameter getPortListening]
                                          AndSocketTimeout: [self._parameter getWaitUdpTotalMillisecond]];
    // update listening port for IPv6
    [self._parameter setListeningPort6:self._server.port];
    if (DEBUG_ON) {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask app server port is %d",self._server.port);
    }
    
    if (localInetAddr4!=nil) {
        self._localInetAddrData = [ESP_NetUtil getLocalInetAddress4ByAddr:localInetAddr4];
    } else {
        int localPort = [self._parameter getPortListening];
        self._localInetAddrData = [ESP_NetUtil getLocalInetAddress6ByPort:localPort];
    }
    
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        // for ESPTouchGenerator only receive 4 bytes for local address no matter IPv4 or IPv6
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask executeForResult() localInetAddr: %@", [ESP_NetUtil descriptionInetAddr4ByData:self._localInetAddrData]);
    }
    
    self._isSuc = NO;
    self._isInterrupt = NO;
    self._isWakeUp = NO;
    self._isExecutedAlready = NO;
    self._condition = [[NSCondition alloc]init];
    self._isSsidHidden = YES;
    self._esptouchResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self._bssidTaskSucCountDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    self._esptouchResultArrayCondition = [[NSCondition alloc]init];
    }
return self;
}

- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd {
return [self initWithApSsid:apSsid andApBssid:apBssid andApPwd:apPwd andAES:nil];
}

- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd andIsSsidHiden: (BOOL) isSsidHidden
{
return [self initWithApSsid:apSsid andApBssid:apBssid andApPwd:apPwd];
}

- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd andTimeoutMillisecond: (int) timeoutMillisecond
{
ESPTouchTask *_self = [self initWithApSsid:apSsid andApBssid:apBssid andApPwd:apPwd];
if (_self)
{
    [_self._parameter setWaitUdpTotalMillisecond:timeoutMillisecond];
}
return _self;
}

- (id) initWithApSsid: (NSString *)apSsid andApBssid: (NSString *) apBssid andApPwd: (NSString *)apPwd andIsSsidHiden: (BOOL) isSsidHidden andTimeoutMillisecond: (int) timeoutMillisecond
{
return [self initWithApSsid:apSsid andApBssid:apBssid andApPwd:apPwd andTimeoutMillisecond:timeoutMillisecond];
}

- (void) __putEsptouchResultIsSuc: (BOOL) isSuc AndBssid: (NSString *)bssid AndInetAddr:(NSData *)inetAddr
{
[self._esptouchResultArrayCondition lock];
// check whether the result receive enough UDP response
BOOL isTaskSucCountEnough = NO;
NSNumber *countNumber = [self._bssidTaskSucCountDict objectForKey:bssid];
int count = 0;
if (countNumber != nil)
{
    count = [countNumber intValue];
}
++count;
if (DEBUG_ON)
{
    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __putEsptouchResult(): count = %d",count);
}
countNumber = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:count];
[self._bssidTaskSucCountDict setObject:countNumber forKey:bssid];
isTaskSucCountEnough = count >= [self._parameter getThresholdSucBroadcastCount];
if (!isTaskSucCountEnough)
{
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __putEsptouchResult(): count = %d, isn't enough", count);
    }
    [self._esptouchResultArrayCondition unlock];
    return;
}
// check whether the result is in the mEsptouchResultList already
BOOL isExist = NO;
for (id esptouchResultId in self._esptouchResultArray)
{
    ESPTouchResult *esptouchResultInArray = esptouchResultId;
    if ([esptouchResultInArray.bssid isEqualToString:bssid])
    {
        isExist = YES;
        break;
    }
}
// only add the result who isn't in the mEsptouchResultList
if (!isExist)
{
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __putEsptouchResult(): put one more result");
    }
    ESPTouchResult *esptouchResult = [[ESPTouchResult alloc]initWithIsSuc:isSuc andBssid:bssid andInetAddrData:inetAddr];
    [self._esptouchResultArray addObject:esptouchResult];
    if (self._esptouchDelegate != nil)
    {
        [self._esptouchDelegate onEsptouchResultAddedWithResult:esptouchResult];
    }
    }
[self._esptouchResultArrayCondition unlock];
}

-(NSArray *) __getEsptouchResultList
{
[self._esptouchResultArrayCondition lock];
if ([self._esptouchResultArray count] == 0)
{
    ESPTouchResult *esptouchResult = [[ESPTouchResult alloc]initWithIsSuc:NO andBssid:nil andInetAddrData:nil];
    esptouchResult.isCancelled = self.isCancelled;
    [self._esptouchResultArray addObject:esptouchResult];
}
[self._esptouchResultArrayCondition unlock];
return self._esptouchResultArray;
}


- (void) beginBackgroundTask
{
if (DEBUG_ON)
{
    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask beginBackgroundTask() entrance");
}
self._backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask beginBackgroundTask() endBackgroundTask");
    }
    [self endBackgroundTask];
}];
}

- (void) endBackgroundTask
{
if (DEBUG_ON)
{
    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask endBackgroundTask() entrance");
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self._backgroundTask];
self._backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}

- (void) __listenAsyn: (const int) expectDataLen
{
dispatch_queue_t  queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self beginBackgroundTask];
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() start an asyn listen task, current thread is: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    }
    NSTimeInterval startTimestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
  //        NSString *apSsidAndPwd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self._apSsid,self._apPwd];
    Byte expectOneByte = [self._apSsid length] + [self._apPwd length] + 9;
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() expectOneByte: %d",expectOneByte);
    }
    Byte receiveOneByte = -1;
    NSData *receiveData = nil;
    while ([self._esptouchResultArray count] < [self._parameter getExpectTaskResultCount] && !self._isInterrupt)
    {
        if ([self._parameter isIPv4Supported]) {
            receiveData = [self._server receiveSpecLenBytes4:expectDataLen];
        } else {
            receiveData = [self._server receiveSpecLenBytes6:expectDataLen];
        }
        if (receiveData != nil)
        {
            [receiveData getBytes:&receiveOneByte length:1];
        }
        else
        {
            receiveOneByte = -1;
        }
        if (receiveOneByte == expectOneByte)
        {
            if (DEBUG_ON)
            {
                NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() receive correct broadcast");
            }
            // change the socket's timeout
            NSTimeInterval consume = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - startTimestamp;
            int timeout = (int)([self._parameter getWaitUdpTotalMillisecond] - consume*1000);
            if (timeout < 0)
            {
                if (DEBUG_ON)
                {
                    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() esptouch timeout");
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (DEBUG_ON)
                {
                    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() socketServer's new timeout is %d milliseconds",timeout);
                }
                [self._server setSocketTimeout:timeout];
                if (DEBUG_ON)
                {
                    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() receive correct broadcast");
                }
                if (receiveData != nil)
                {
                    NSString *bssid =
                    [ESP_ByteUtil parseBssid:(Byte *)[receiveData bytes]
                                      Offset:[self._parameter getEsptouchResultOneLen]
                                       Count:[self._parameter getEsptouchResultMacLen]];
                    NSData *inetAddrData =
                    [ESP_NetUtil parseInetAddrByData:receiveData
                                           andOffset:[self._parameter getEsptouchResultOneLen] + [self._parameter getEsptouchResultMacLen]
                                            andCount:[self._parameter getEsptouchResultIpLen]];
                    [self __putEsptouchResultIsSuc:YES AndBssid:bssid AndInetAddr:inetAddrData];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (DEBUG_ON)
            {
                NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() receive rubbish message, just ignore");
            }
        }
    }
    self._isSuc = [self._esptouchResultArray count] >= [self._parameter getExpectTaskResultCount];
    [self __interrupt];
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() finish");
    }
    [self endBackgroundTask];
    });
 }

 - (void) interrupt
{
if (DEBUG_ON)
{
    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask interrupt()");
}
self.isCancelled = YES;
[self __interrupt];
}

- (void) __interrupt
{
self._isInterrupt = YES;
[self._client interrupt];
[self._server interrupt];
// notify the ESPTouchTask to wake up from sleep mode
[self __notify];
}

- (BOOL) __execute: (ESPTouchGenerator *)generator
{
    NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = startTime;
    NSTimeInterval lastTime = currentTime - [self._parameter 
    getTimeoutTotalCodeMillisecond];

NSArray *gcBytes2 = [generator getGCBytes2];
NSArray *dcBytes2 = [generator getDCBytes2];

int index = 0;

while (!self._isInterrupt)
{
    if (currentTime - lastTime >= [self._parameter getTimeoutTotalCodeMillisecond]/1000.0)
    {
        if (DEBUG_ON)
        {
            NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __execute() send gc code ");
        }
        // send guide code
        while (!self._isInterrupt && [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - currentTime < [self._parameter getTimeoutGuideCodeMillisecond]/1000.0)
        {
            [self._client sendDataWithBytesArray2:gcBytes2
                                 ToTargetHostName:[self._parameter getTargetHostname]
                                         WithPort:[self._parameter getTargetPort]
                                      andInterval:[self._parameter getIntervalGuideCodeMillisecond]];
            // check whether the udp is send enough time
            if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - startTime > [self._parameter getWaitUdpSendingMillisecond]/1000.0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        lastTime = currentTime;
    }
    else
    {
        [self._client sendDataWithBytesArray2:dcBytes2
                                       Offset:index
                                        Count:ONE_DATA_LEN
                             ToTargetHostName:[self._parameter getTargetHostname]
                                     WithPort:[self._parameter getTargetPort]
                                  andInterval:[self._parameter getIntervalDataCodeMillisecond]];
        index = (index + ONE_DATA_LEN) % [dcBytes2 count];
    }
    currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    // check whether the udp is send enough time
    if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - startTime > [self._parameter getWaitUdpSendingMillisecond]/1000.0)
    {
        break;
    }
}

    return self._isSuc;
}

- (void) __checkTaskValid
{
    if (self._isExecutedAlready)
    {
        perror("ESPTouchTask __checkTaskValid() fail, the task could be executed only once");
    }
    // !!!NOTE: the esptouch task could be executed only once
    assert(!self._isExecutedAlready);
   self._isExecutedAlready = YES;
}

- (ESPTouchResult *) executeForResult
{
    return [[self executeForResults:1] objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (NSArray*) executeForResults:(int) expectTaskResultCount
{
    // set task result count
    if (expectTaskResultCount <= 0)
     {
         expectTaskResultCount = INT32_MAX;
     }
    [self._parameter setExpectTaskResultCount:expectTaskResultCount];

    [self __checkTaskValid];

    // generator the esptouch byte[][] to be transformed, which will cost
    // some time(maybe a bit much)
ESPTouchGenerator *generator = [[ESPTouchGenerator alloc]initWithSsid:self._apSsid andApBssid:self._apBssid andApPassword:self._apPwd andInetAddrData:self._localInetAddrData andIsSsidHidden:self._isSsidHidden];
// listen the esptouch result asyn
[self __listenAsyn:[self._parameter getEsptouchResultTotalLen]];
BOOL isSuc = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < [self._parameter getTotalRepeatTime]; i++)
{
    isSuc = [self __execute:generator];
    if (isSuc)
    {
        return [self __getEsptouchResultList];
    }
}

if (!self._isInterrupt)
{
    [self __sleep: [self._parameter getWaitUdpReceivingMillisecond]];
    [self __interrupt];
}

    return [self __getEsptouchResultList];
}

// sleep some milliseconds
- (BOOL) __sleep :(long) milliseconds
{
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __sleep() start");
    }
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: milliseconds/1000.0];
    [self._condition lock];
    BOOL signaled = NO;
    while (!self._isWakeUp && (signaled = [self._condition waitUntilDate:date]))
    {
    }
    [self._condition unlock];
    if (DEBUG_ON)
    {
        NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __sleep() end, receive signal is %@", signaled ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }
    return signaled;
 }

 // notify the sleep thread to wake up
- (void) __notify
{
    if (DEBUG_ON)
{
    NSLog(@"ESPTouchTask __notify()");
}
[self._condition lock];
self._isWakeUp = YES;
[self._condition signal];
[self._condition unlock];
 }

- (void) setEsptouchDelegate: (NSObject<ESPTouchDelegate> *) esptouchDelegate
{
    self._esptouchDelegate = esptouchDelegate;
}

- (void)setPackageBroadcast:(BOOL)broadcast {
[self._parameter setBroadcast:broadcast];
}

@end
```

and call this
in my view Struct in Swiftui

```
    func executeForResults(ssid: String?, bssid: String?, password: String?, taskCount: Int, broadcast: Bool) -> [Any]? {
    condition.lock()
    esptouchTask = ESPTouchTask(apSsid: ssid, andApBssid: bssid, andApPwd: password)
    esptouchTask?.setEsptouchDelegate(esptouchDelegate)
    esptouchTask?.setPackageBroadcast(true)
    print("pass")
    let esptouchResults = esptouchTask?.execute(forResults: Int32(taskCount))
    print("ESPViewController executeForResult() result is: \(String(describing: esptouchResults))")
    return esptouchResults
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried getting the simplest thing possible working first, with respect to a SwiftUI/Objective-C app? There is a very good article on this, here: // https://medium.com/@iainbarclay/adding-swiftui-to-objective-c-apps-63abc3b26c33

Comment: Hi Mario, Thanks for your suggestion. However I did already connect all the objective c files to my swiftui code. and I am getting the ssid and bssid data from it. but to finish to connect esp32 device I need to broadcast and find the device which is I am getting the error " "No visible @interface for 'ESPTaskParameter' declares the selector 'setBroadcast:'". and this is the problem....TT

Comment: Okay, are we talking about the same ESPTaskParameter class that I find at the following URL? Because if I go to this page, where the class is documented, and then search for the setBroadcast method you're talking about, there is none—which would explain what you're seeing. http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ESPTouchiOS/0.3.5.3/Classes/ESPTaskParameter.html

Comment: I actually used this source code https://github.com/EspressifApp/EsptouchForIOS/tree/master/EspTouchDemo/ESPTouch/task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your code for where the @interface for ESPTaskParameter is defined, that will be in some .h file. Then, make sure the .m file #imports that header file. If it doesn’t the there would indeed be no visible interface defining the selector you want to call to the .m file that is trying to call it

And check that the interface .h does indeed declare a public setter for broadcast.

Comment: As my shallow knowledge I see All you mentioned is in both .m .h files as you see above. in ESPTouchTask.h @interface ESPTouchTask : NSObject - (void) setPackageBroadcast: (BOOL) broadcast;